# Why is concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() skipping iterations?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I have a function that I parallelise using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()` something like this:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(my_func, ids, it.repeat(num_ids))
```

Where `ids` is a list of tuples that are formed of two elements. The first element contains an integer that ascends by 1 for each subsequent tuple. I use this to create an 'iteration progress tracker'. The second element contains an input `my_func` uses.

`my_func` is too lengthy to add here and I haven't been able to get an MRE that has reciprocal behaviour. However, it looks something like this:

```
def my_func(id, num_ids):
    print(f"{id[0]} of {num_ids}")
    # Extract something from a database, transform it and then add the new data back into the database
```

On one run I noticed that at around 5k on the iteration tracker it suddenly jumped to 10k, stuttered and then kept going. After that it skipped some more records every so often. This pattern repeats if I run the code again but the skips happen in slightly different places each time.

I duly kicked into debug mode in VS Code but to my surprise no records were skipped when running the code from the debugger. No errors, nothing.

The only way I've found to stop the skipping outside of the debugger is to set the `max_workers` argument to half of my threads.

I realise without an MRE this is difficult to diagnose but I'm hoping someone else may have experienced this issue or recognises these symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy to answer for the specific case given the information provided.
My best guess is that an exception occurs in the body of `my_func`.
Indeed, if an exception occurs, nothing is going to be printed and the execution is not going to terminate.
To validate my assumption, I would define a decorator to print the exception occurring in the function:

```
import functools

def log_function(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(args, kwargs, repr(exc))

    return wrapper
```

and apply the decorator to the function.

```
@log_function
def my_func(my_id, num_ids):
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this though an error will usually show up in the debugger even when running in parallel.

Comment: It found the error :) Turns out it was a database connection error so I think I'm maxing out my connection somehow. Thanks a million for the above!